# Espresso click on webView button

Tags: android, webview, android-espresso

Hello I need to click on web view in my test. Button in webView code has following code:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="ignoreClose()" name="UsernamePasswordEntry" value="Submit">
```

I try to handle it like that:

```
   onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME, "UsernamePasswordEntry")).perform(webClick());
```

But I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Atom evaluation returned null!
```

Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: have you tried with the some other attribute such as id of the html tag?

Comment: Issue is caused by fact that button is not inside my website code but inside iframe where Espresso doesn't have access. I still didn't figured out how to click on part of website displayed inside webView which is created from few iframes.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `Locator.XPATH`, ex.

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "here put XPATH")).perform(webClick())
```

To get `XPATH`, just go to inspect elements on Web and right click on marked element and just copy `XPATH`

Comment: onWebView() method returns webview with null elements.. Even when the web page is loaded in the device while running tests...Any reasons?

Comment: I have tried with above method using www.google.com to click Sign in button using xPath //*[@id="gb"]/div/div[2]/a . but, am getting this error.                             java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 32 value:
 {message=Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression Sign in because of the following error:
 SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'Sign in' is not a valid XPath expression.
}